# Manage cache of MapView

Tags: android, google-maps

I've made an application based on the Google Maps API. The problem is that my application is made to be used in the wild, in places where there is no network.
 So I would like to manage the cache in order to ensure that specific tiles are saved and available during the trip (I'd like to redirect them in database but any method may do).

For now, I didn't found any other method (not tested) than try to recode the MapView class. I'm focusing on Google API in order to have satellite photography (for places where there are no roads). What could I do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is in violation of the [Android Maps APIs Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-api-signup.html) (see section 8.2). You will need to find an alternative mapping engine to use, perhaps based on [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).

Comment: The mapping engine is not the problem, the true problem is to access satellite data...



But I didn't see this 8.2 section before. So I'll have to look for another provider of maps than google :(
I still don't know why they didn't offer cache management facilities...

Answer (score 3):

osmdroid now provides a library that can almost be used as a Google Maps replacement. It can support offline maps by downloading and extracting AndNav map tiles.

http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

Comment: Is there a way using this library to access satellite view ? It doesn't seem so. My software is dedicated to mountain hiking where there are no roads, so the precise satellite view is the greatest requirement...