# how to save cached data to sqlite DB (android)

Tags: android, sqlite, caching

hey , I want to cache google maps, and put them into the memory, using sqlite DB,so that I don't have to always use the internet connection! is that possible? and if it is possible I would like to know how? 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

As noted [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176995/manage-cache-of-mapview/2177066#2177066), this is a violation of the terms of service.